# Angular 5 nested dynamic subcategory does not work correctly

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm working on angular 5 and django rest as backend the `datas` is comming from my server im trying to show sub category of my category next to it parent .by this code last subcategory will show top of its parent always. also subcategory `ul` will repeat twice.. i spend much time but i cant fix it ... anyone know how can i fix this issue?

```
public hoveredCategory: any;
public hoveredsCategory: any;

ngOnInit() {

    this.datas = [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "develop"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "business"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "parent_id": 12,
        "title": "web"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "parent_id": 14,
        "title": "php"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "parent_id": 14,
        "title": "asp"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "parent_id": 12,
        "title": "android"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "parent_id": 18,
        "title": "java"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "parent_id": 13,
        "title": "speach"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "parent_id": 20,
        "title": "full"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "parent_id": 20,
        "title": "mini"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "parent_id": 13,
        "title": "no speach"
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "parent_id": 14,
        "title": "html"
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "parent_id": 23,
        "title": "nospech2"
    }
]

      this.categories = this.datas.filter(c => c.parent_id === null).map(title => <{ title: string, sub: any, subsub: object[] }> {
        title: title.title,
        sub: this.datas.filter(sc => sc.parent_id === title.id)
          .map(sc => <{ title: string, sub: any }> {
            title: sc.title,
            sub: this.datas.filter(c => c.parent_id !== null && sc.id === c.parent_id).map(ss => <{ secondSub: object[] }> {secondSub: ss.title})
          }),

      });
  hover(event, category) {
    this.hoveredCategory = category;    
  }

  hoversc(event, category) {
    this.hoveredsCategory = category;
  }
```

**html:**

```
<ul id='menu' class="right">
  <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Menu'><span id="cat" class="ion-android-apps"></span></a>
    <ul class='menus'>
      <li class='has-submenu' *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        <a class='prett' href='#'
           (mouseover)="hover($event, cat)">{{ cat.title }}
        </a>
        <ul class='submenu'>
          <li>
            <a href="#" title="Sub Menu" *ngFor="let sc of hoveredCategory?.sub" (mouseover)="hoversc($event, sc.sub)">{{ sc.title }}</a>
            <ul class='subsubmenu'>
              <li *ngFor="let ssc of hoveredsCategory">
                <a href="#" title="Sub Menu">{{ ssc.secondSub }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css code:

```
#menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 80px;
  top: 18px;
  border: none;
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #007791;
}

#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul.menus {
  display: block
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #f2f3f5;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}

#menu ul.menus .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 120px;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
}

#menu ul.menus .has-submenu:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul.menus .has-submenu .submenu:hover .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I have seen that your *this.categories* array is uptodate with all main and sub category menu so you are again construct variable on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hoveredsCategory` value doesn't cleaned. So when hover events occurs in different category old `hoveredsCategory` is preserved. So restore `hoveredsCategory` on `hover`:

```
 hover(event, category) {
  //  console.log('hover', category)
    this.hoveredCategory = category;
    this.hoveredsCategory = null;
  }
```

[StackBlitz EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bysa4e)

Comment: thanks ... when we hover on develop->android ,
java will open on top of menu but it should open beside android can you fix it ?

Comment: perfect! how did you fixed that ?

Comment: @mohreza, look code. If somewhere in code isn't clear, I will answer you late. let me know

Comment: its clear thanks .. one more question somthing like
`  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;` for .menu not work ... is there anyway to apply our effect on it ?

Comment: @mohreza, play with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7n67zu. One rule is `li` elements should be removed/added from/to html to apply animation in code example. Read more: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: in your stackblitz why when we hover on parent category all catgory will apear too ? for example hover on develop will show java too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168039/discussion-between-yerkon-and-moh-reza).